# Best way to have just single instance of job at time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, rate-limiting

I have a Spring Rest Controller endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/someheavyjob")
public Response indexAllReports() {
    someService.startLongRunningOperation();
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

and then in the service class I have a method which performs many computations (databse read, other API calls etc.) :

```
public void startLongRunningOperation(){
 List<String> involvedIds = otherApi.getAllActiveMembersIds(..);
 involvedIds.forEach(id -> {
 anotherComputatioMethod();
 });
}
```

I know that this approach is bloking user's request until complete the job. I can solve it, it's in that state just to make it clear.
Quesiton: What I am considering about it is:

- There should be only one instance of this heavy method running at a time (method: startLongRunningOperation).
  Right now, as this method can be invoked from Rest controller, each api call will start this heavy method in new thread. There are mechanisms to rate limit users requests in java (eg. bucket4j), but wanted to ask you guys, what is the best way to handle this case ? Just one instance of long running task fired from Rest API calling Spring Service (which is and should be stateless) .

**Edit 1:**
To make it clear - blocking: I mean user have to wait for response unit whole task is finished - it can take minutes.
What I want to achieve is not to make this service method synchronized, but when the request comes, and in that time this long running task is working, then reject that 2nd request.

Comment: *each api call will start this heavy method in new thread* - I don't see any threads created and the method is **sync**

Comment: So if two rest requests are coming and the first one manages to run the long operation (and gets blocked till this operation gets done) what is the expected behavior of the second thread? Do you want it to become blocked and only when the first operation gets done run this operation again? Do you want to return an immediate response of "server is busy now, try later" style? Please clarify to get the best answer

Comment: If `someService` is a singleton, you can make `startLongRunningOperation` a synchronized method.

Comment: Each Rest API request is executed in separate thread - this is Spring default behaviour. Nothing is blocking so far - two requests - two threads executing this method. I want to reject second call to this endpoint (which means calling this long running method).

Service is singleton. Making this method synchronized is one of the possible solution (without rejecting 2nd call), is there any other ? For sure, want to know. (Don't trust synchroznized)